# Xamarin.Forms app using Azure AD B2C only showing Microsoft login

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I’m developing a Xamarin app that uses Azure AD B2C and I’m having some trouble.

Even though I have LinkedIn, Google, Microsoft, Facebook, and Twitter setup as Identity Providers, the only thing I am ever prompted for is my Microsoft account.  I don’t see any of the other buttons when my app invokes the login.  Works great for Microsoft login, can’t access any of the others.

Here is my call to AcquireTokenAsync:

```
var result = await AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, 
    GetUserByPolicy(App.AuthenticationClient.Users, Constants.PolicySignUpSignIn), 
    Evaluator.App.UiParent);
```

In the Azure AD B2C settings in the portal, I have Web App / Web API set to NO, Native client set to YES.  The Custom Redirect URI is “masl{myappid}://auth”.
Under Keys it says “No results”.
Under API access (Preview) it says there are 2 scopes (both checkboxes checked for openid and offline_access).
Under published scopes (Preview) it says Web app / Web API has not been included.

Under Identity providers, I have LinkedIn, Google, Microsoft, Facebook, and Twitter configured.

Comment: What auth library is this? Xamarin.Auth?

Comment: @ethane I believe they are using MSAL .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that changing to use one of the other overloads of AcquireTokenAsync causes different behavior.

```
var result = //await AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.AuthenticationClient.Users, Constants.PolicySignUpSignIn), Evaluator.App.UiParent);
    await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.AuthenticationClient.Users, Constants.PolicySignUpSignIn), UIBehavior.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, Constants.Authority, App.UiParent);
```

The original call caused the Azure AD service to be called, and the call shown here causes the Azure B2C service to be called instead.  I don't see that documented anywhere, and I wish all the overloads had better documentation describing the relevance and distinctions in behavior between them.

Now I see all the providers I had configured showing up as options!  However, there's a new problem in that (despite the fact that they appear to be configured correctly) I no longer get an email address back in the `result.User.DisplayableId` field.  Despite this, my original question is answered.

Comment: [Document the prompt parameter](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5464)

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Policy Identity Providers (IDPs)

[image: configure policy idps screenshot]

[Sample Policy](https://login.microsoftonline.com/spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SO-Mark-Snyder&client_id=d39bf8bf-dc0a-47c6-8c55-fb0aada53d23&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login)

[image: login screenshot]

Comment: That wasn't it.  I have already done that for each of the providers that I listed in the op.

Comment: Bummer.  I figured such but wasn't 100% sure @MarkSnyder